# ts-delayed-delta : deletes from core but does not run delta index

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job, thinking-sphinx

I am running into an issue on one of my app using Thinking Sphinx and Delayed Delta.

It was rencently updated from Rails 3 + TS 2 to Rails 4 + TS 3 and since then, delta indexing is not working.

Used gems :

- thinking-sphinx : 3.1.4
- ts-delayed-delta : 2.0.2
- delayed_job : 4.1.1

Digging into the issue, I can see that, when updating my object, the outdated object is removed from the `_core` index but the updated object is not indexed in the `_delta` index.

**Before modifying my object :**

- Search without the `:indices` option return the object.
- Search on the `_core` index (using `:indices` option) returns the object.
- Search on the `_delta` index (using `:indices` option) does not.

**After modifying the object :**

- Search without the `:indices` option does not return the object.
- Search on the `_core` index (using `:indices` option) does not return the object.
- Search on the `_delta` index (using `:indices` option) does not return the object.

**After running `ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::IndexJob.new('object_delta').perform`** (thus running the delta indexing)

- Search without the `:indices` option return the object.
- Search on the `_core` index (using `:indices` option) does not return the object.
- Search on the `_delta` index (using `:indices` option) does not.

I then noticed why this happens : only one job was added to the delayed_job queue and performed, the `ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DelayedDelta::FlagAsDeletedJob`.

The `ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DelayedDelta::DeltaJob` that would run the indexation of the modified objetcs in the `_delta` is not added to the queue.

Would anyone knows why this is hapenning and how to solve this ?

**Update : Index definition.**

I have two index for the same model (these are localized index) and both have delta enabled.

Here is how they are defined in `product_variant_index.rb`:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define 'products/product_variant', :with => :active_record, :name => 'variant_nl', :delta => ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DelayedDelta do
     ... [Index definition]
end

ThinkingSphinx::Index.define 'products/product_variant', :with => :active_record, :name => 'variant_fr', :delta => ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DelayedDelta do
     ... [Index definition]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the source code of ts-delayed-delta, the only reason I can see for the DeltaJob not being scheduled is that a duplicate exists that hasn't locked/failed. I don't suppose this is the case here?

https://github.com/pat/ts-delayed-delta/blob/master/lib/thinking_sphinx/deltas/delayed_delta.rb#L25-L27

Comment: I saw te samecondition in the source. But your supposition is correct : it is not the case here : delayed_job table is empty.

But that's the Binary module. Isn't the SphinxQL module used with TS3 ? This module has 2 methods : index and delete. could it be that only eh delete method is run ? then why ?

Comment: The relevant code in TS is here: https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/blob/master/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/callbacks/delta_callbacks.rb#L11 - you'll see the `index` method is called for every delta index, and then the `delete` method is called for every core index. Are you configuring delta indices in a non-standard manner?

Comment: Also: https://github.com/pat/ts-delayed-delta/blob/master/lib/thinking_sphinx/deltas/delayed_delta.rb#L125 - this is where the SphinxQL module calls `enqueue_unless_duplicates`.

Comment: I edited my question to show how delta are configured in my index file.

Comment: Okay, there's nothing particularly odd there… so right now, I don't know why this is happening.